# Check Internet Connectivity in cordova using visual studio

Tags: javascript, cordova

Am using cordova with visual studio 2015

now I am checking internet connectivity

so i tried this [reference link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/how-to-detect-device-is-connected-to-internet-using-cordova/)

html:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

In JS:

```
if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
        alert("offline");
    } else {
        alert("online");
    }
```

error:

> Cannot read property 'network' of undefined

How to solve this issue, and how to find the find the internet connectivity.
Is this proper way to find the internet connection ?

Comment: Have you install the network plugin ?
You can find the doc here : 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-network-information/

Comment: please install plugin from config.xml [network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information#quick-example)

Comment: Yes i have installed, but still network is undefined and also i tried this too `navigator.connection.type`

Comment: Any other steps to do ?? anybody ??

Comment: Could you please share a demo that can reproduce this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this library , without any external plugins it works just fine :
https://github.com/PixelsCommander/OnlineJS

Comment: Maybe we can find a way to get their existing library to work, as requested, instead of suggesting a new one?

Comment: @Amy Cordova network plugin is actually checking network status but it doesn't guarantee that there is an internet access . And he mentioned "Is this proper way to find the internet connection ?"